# Method chains with nameof operator

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

If I do `nameof(instance.SomeProperty)`, it evaluates to `"SomeProperty"`.

Is there any way I can get the entire method chain `"instance.SomeProperty"`?

I know I could do `nameof(instance) + "." + nameof(instance.SomeProperty)`, but is there a better way that's more maintainable?

Comment: `$"{nameof(instance)}.{nameof(instance.SomeProperty)}"`

Comment: that doesn't really fall into the scope of the intended purpose of `nameof`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way I can get the entire method chain "instance.SomeProperty"?

Nope. You can, however, do something similar to your other solution:

```
$"{nameof(instance)}.{nameof(instance.SomeProperty)}"
```

You can try it [here](http://csharppad.com/gist/c2db3f4c3d67240f1d1f).

Answer (score 3):

My 5 cents:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(Name.Of<A>(x => x.B.Hehe)); // outputs "B.Hehe"

        var a = new A();
        Console.WriteLine(Name.Of(() => a.B.Hehe));   // outputs "B.Hehe"
    }

    public class A {
        public B B { get; } // property
    } 

    public class B {
        public int Hehe; // or field, does not matter
    } 
}

public static class Name 
{
    public static string Of(this Expression<Func<object>> expression) => Of(expression.Body);

    public static string Of<T>(this Expression<Func<T, object>> expression) => Of(expression.Body);

    public static string Of(this Expression expression)
    {
        switch (expression)
        {
            case MemberExpression m:                
                var prefix = Of(m.Expression);
                return (prefix == "" ? "" : prefix + ".") + m.Member.Name;
            case UnaryExpression u when u.Operand is MemberExpression m:
                return Of(m);
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is nice. maybe the only way to get the complete statement as a string. These are not 5 cents these are at least 20 cents for sure ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. The `nameof` operator just yields the property (or class, field, etc) at the end of the expression, so `nameof(Program.Main)` will yield `Main`, and so does `nameof(ConsoleAppliation1.Program.Main)`.

The `nameof` operator wasn't meant to do what you ask. It is just prevent passing names around for event handlers, dependency properties, etc. that depend on the sole name of the property / class name. All other fancy stuff you want to do is on your own.

Like [M.kazem Akhgary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4767498/m-kazem-akhgary) commented, you can do this yourself by constructing the expression yourself:

```
$"{nameof(instance)}.{nameof(instance.SomeProperty)}"
```